# Search network PCs for user SID

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, sid

I have been looking into how to find the location of a SID on network computers but so far nothing.

I need to search our network, and query all PC's find if a specific SID is present and to give me the resulting PCs where this user SID appears.

Any ideas as I am drawing a blank.

Comment: Are your users in a domain? Can you access all computers through powershell remoting?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Find which computer a user is currently logged on to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. Takes the username, converts to SID, then searches all the computers in the domain for that SID in the registry (user has to be logged on otherwise the registry key doesn't exist).

```
$User = "Username"
$SID = Get-ADUser -Identity $User | Select -ExpandProperty SID
$ComputerList = Get-ADComputer -Filter * | Select -ExpandProperty DNSHostName

foreach ($Computer in $ComputerList){
    if (Test-Connection -ComputerName $Computer -Quiet -Count 1) {
        $Reg = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey('Users', $Computer)
        if ($Reg.OpenSubKey("$SID")) {
            Write-Output "$User found on $Computer."
        }
        else {
            Write-Output "$User not found on $Computer."
        }
    }
    else {
        Write-Output "$Computer unreachable."
    }
}
```